# Cannot remove bootcamp partition

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

My mac (running El Capitan) has recently run out of storage space so I have been trying to remove my bootcamp partition to restore the full capacity of the OS X partition.

When I try to remove it through the bootcamp assistant I receive a message saying

> An error occurred while verifying the file system. Please reboot into
>   recovery, repair the disk with Disk Utility, then try the operation
>   again.

I have tried to boot into recovery and repair the disk, however, it says everything has been repaired and the bootcamp assistant still fails.

After this I went into terminal and ran `diskutil list` with the output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            174.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                75.6 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +174.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 01CA9FDB-EE71-4B65-9216-2A7EB5CBA511
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Next, I tried to erase the disk with `diskutil eraseVolume fat32 BOOTCAMP disk0s4` which worked, however, I am still unable to merge the partition in Bootcamp assistant and I am given the same error message.

Any ideas on how to merge the partitions and remove the Bootcamp partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been posted many times before. Why not once more. The commands are given below.

```
diskutil  eraseVolume  free  n  disk0s4
diskutil  cs  resizeStack  01CA9FDB-EE71-4B65-9216-2A7EB5CBA511  0
```

If any of the above commands fail, you can try to repair macOS volume by entering the following command.

```
sudo diskutil repairVolume disk0s2
```

If the repair command does not resolve issues, then you have the following options:

- Erase the disk and reload from a time machine backup.
- Backup your files, reformat the partition, reinstall the macOS, the reload your files.

Comment: When I run the `resizeStack` command I receive the error message `The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 01CA9FDB-EE71-4B65-9216-2A7EB5CBA511
Started CoreStorage operation
Checking prerequisites for resizing Logical-Physical volume stack
Growing Logical-Physical volume stack
Verifying file system
Using live mode
Checking extended attributes file
Volume bitmap needs minor repair for orphaned blocks
Checking volume information
File system check exit code is 8
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed`. Perhaps you would know what the solution to this is?

Comment: @JSS930: I updated my question.