# Unable to remove bootcamp partion

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I was previously using windows on my Macbook pro 2015, on mac OSX 12.6, but now no longer need it. I'd like to remove the partition and revert my laptop to how it was previously when it had more storage space.

The Apple website says to remove it using bootcamp assistant, but when I open bootcamp assistant, there is no option to remove it. The only option available is to install windows. [image]

From looking at some other answers it seems like I might need to use disk utility. There is 70Gb of 'free space', but I'm almost sure it is not really free as this other storage measurement doesn't have 70Gb free, so I think it is from the windows partition.
[image][image] I have tried to remove the partition by selecting the minus and then clicking apply, but there seems to be an error during this process.

[image]
I followed the instructions to run first aid, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Also trying to restart my Macbook while pressing option no longer gives me the option to go into windows, so I'm not sure why this option has disappeared, but I have not removed windows previously.

I'm not very confident using the terminal, so despite seeing some other similar questions with solutions, I'm hesitant to copy over some terminal code from a different question, in case I miss something and cause more issues.

Would a following a solution like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/cannot-remove-bootcamp-partition) be appropriate?

Running diskutil list in the terminal seems to be a common theme among the other answers so I have put it here too.
[image]

Thank you and apologies for the repeated question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have posted, there are no Windows partition on the Mac's internal drive. If you cannot repair the APFS container partition, then you will probably need to backup your files, erase the internal drive and reinstall macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just ran first aid in recovery mode, and also tried removing the 'free space' partition from within recovery mode, and it seemed to work. I now have 90Gb of storage available. Thanks again!